# Updating data in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Have a question about updating data.
Apologies in advance for this analogy.

Let's imagine that there is a `List <Object>` of objects (for example, names of dishes)
Each object has a `List <String>` field (list of ingredients)

And let's say a case has arisen when a chef, depending on the country or laws, removes some ingredient from all dishes

What to do in this case, if some of that record is already repeated in many dishes, or even in each?
Checking each object and updating its `List <String>` is not an option since `O (n)` will take a very long time

```
public class SOME_CLASS_NAME {
    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private @Id
    String dishId;

    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private List<String> groups;

    @Field(type = Keyword)
    private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Comment: You should post the Java class representing the ES document.  The answer is, it depends on how you are storing this data in ElasticSearch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added

Comment: One option here might be to just store all ingredients as a single text string.  This would still be searchable, and can be updated by removing a single ingredient.